# Control structures and comparison operators

Tags: php

Here is an empty array, this is followed by a for loop which runs the block ten times.

Inside the block, I added the control section by adding elements to the array each time it loops around. I want each element to be a string containing a single letter, based on the value of the loops index:
The letter "a" if $i is less than 4.
The letter "b" if $i is between 4 and 7.
The letter "c" if $i is greater than or equal to 8.

When I try adding the element to the array. I wanted to use it directly for the index array-like 
$array[1] = "a";

or have it empty, which I can have the values appended to the end of the array automatically when assigning the index.
$array[] = "a";

so here's my code:

```php
<?php

$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    if ($i < 4) {
        echo $array[1] = "a";
    } if ($i = 4 and 7 ) {
        echo $array[5] = "b";
    } if ($i >= 8) {
        echo $array[9] = "c";
    }
}

?>
```

What is my main problem and how can I solve it?

Quick update!!!!!

I solved the problem!

Here's the solution

```
<?php

$array = [];

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    if ($i < 4) {
    echo $array[] = "a";
    } elseif ($i >= 4 && $i <= 7) {
    echo $array[] = "b";
    } elseif ($i >= 8) {
    echo $array[] = "c";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 2):

`$i = 4 and 7` is not valid for several reasons (`=` is assignment).  It can't be *4 AND 7* both. Probably *greater than or equal to 4* AND *less than or equal to 7*.  Also, you should use `elseif` since you're comparing a single value and it can't be more than one:

```
if ($i < 4) {
    echo $array[1] = "a";
} elseif ($i >= 4 && $i <= 7) {
    echo $array[5] = "b";
} elseif ($i >= 8) {  // probably ($i > 7)
    echo $array[9] = "c";
}
```

Not sure, but to keep it consistent, your last condition should probably be: `$i > 7`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$i = 4` in if condition you always assign 4 to `$i` and you will see `abbbbbbbb....` as output.

you can do like this:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

foreach ($array as $i => $item) {
    $tmp = 'c';
    if ($item < 8)
        $tmp = "b";
    if ($i < 4 )
        $tmp = "a";
    echo $array[$i] = $tmp;
}
```

Comment: I did this 
```
<?php

$array = [];

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {

     if ($i < 4) {
    echo $array[] = "a";
} elseif ($i >= 4 && $i <= 7) {
    echo $array[] = "b";
} elseif ($i >= 8) { 
    echo $array[] = "c";
}

}
```